# get address line in Arabic from coordinates

Tags: dart, flutter

Am using [Geocoder](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geocoder) plugin to get address line, country, postal code, .... like this:

```
  final coordinates = new Coordinates(26.328446, 50.153868);
  var addresses = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
  var first = addresses.first;
  print(addresses);
  print("${first.featureName} : ${first.addressLine}");
```

and this returns:

> flutter: Zarqa Al Yamamah Street : Zarqa Al Yamamah Street - Al Dana Al Jenobiah, Dhahran 34453, Saudi Arabia

I want to get the same result but in Arabic .. is there is a way to achieve this with this plugin? or there is any other plugins can return address for me in Arabic?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the language code `ar` or  `ar-SA`. So you need to do this:

```
Locale loc = new Locale("ar");
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, loc);
```

or this way

```
geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ar_SA))
```

Your code can be like this

```
           Locale loc = new Locale("ar"); 
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, loc)) 
final coordinates = new Coordinates(26.328446, 50.153868); 
var addresses = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates); 
var first = addresses.first; 
print(addresses); 
print("${first.featureName} : ${first.addressLine}");
```

Do it like this:

```
Geocoder geocoder;
List<Address> addresses;
geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ar_SA)) 



addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5

String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName(); // Only if available else return NULL
```

See this example:

```
import 'package:locales/locales.dart';
import 'package:locales/currency_codes.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  final locale = Locale.ar_SA;
  final currencyCode = CurrencyCode.sar;
  final format = NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(
      locale: '$locale', name: '$currencyCode', decimalDigits: 2);
  print(locale);                  
  print(currencyCode);            
  print(format.format(123.456));  
}
```

https://github.com/jifalops/locales

Comment: i got the error: too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 2 found ..

Comment: try this :`geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ar_SA))`;

Comment: _this_ is what? context?

Comment: and still getting the same error with both ways ... too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 2 found

Comment: getting:  too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 2 found and getFromLocation is not defined in Geocoder

Comment: Can you try it now?

Comment: i got now that local cannot be accessed through an instance

Comment: Sorry , remove `local` from `geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);`  to be `geocoder.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);`

Comment: i tried .. and when i did i got that findAddressesFromCoordinates is not defined in Geocoder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187033/discussion-between-i-th-and-lamatat).

Comment: The code snippets point to different types of codes. OP refers to a flutter plugin, while you provide a solution for another platforms' code. That's why he gets the `too many positional arguments` error

Comment: @Ma250 thank you for your comment.  It worked for him and I updated the answer to match his platform.  You can see the chat.

Comment: @i_th How exactly did it work?
Flutters' `Geocoder` takes no parameters. [its usage is static]
https://pub.dev/packages/geocoder

The code that is suggested above [and in chat] fits Androids' `Geocoder` 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder

Comment: @Ma250 you are right but he used in his code this way ` Locale loc = new Locale("ar_SA");` and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use  specific local you must use **apiKey**

try to replace `Geocoder.local` method with `Geocoder.google` in your code

Like this :

```
Coordinates coordinates = Coordinates(latLng.lat, latLng.lng);

List<Address> addresses =await Geocoder.google(apiKey,language:'ar').findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
```

How to get **apiKey** ? show [Get an API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key#get-the-api-key)